# Touchbegan method not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

touchesBegan methods not called on GMSmapview.I was expecting this method to be called on touching or dragging map .can someone let me know whats wrong with this code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    _mapview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    _mapview.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches
           withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    NSLog(@"touchbegan started"); 
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches
           withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesMoved started");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches
           withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded started");
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use touchesBegan method use GMSmapview mapdiddrag or mapdidtap methods

Comment: i want to get the lat nd log where user touches on the map..can you give brief idea about how to do this

Comment: `for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in self.mapView.recognizers) { if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:UIPanGestureRecognizer]) {recognizer.addTarget...;} }`  might be of some use in this case..

Comment: You need to understand how the touch interaction works (UIResponder chain). The mapview is consuming the touch so the viewController is not getting the touch.  Nice example: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/understanding-cocoa-and-cocoa-touch-responder-chain-12fe558ebe97

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer [GMSMapViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p)

To detect if the user dragged the map I think it's better to use this method

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView willMove:(BOOL)gesture
```

and check if `gesture` argument is `true`.

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
```

The `didChangeCameraPosition` is called, as mentioned, many times but since it's also called by both setting the map center from code and as a result of a gesture you can't really see the difference in that method alone.

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
```

Called before the camera on the map changes, either due to a gesture, animation (e.g., by a user tapping on the "My Location" button) or by being updated explicitly via the camera or a zero-length animation on layer.